# AWS Systems Manager: Enumerate a StringList Parameter in State Manager Document

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-systems-manager

State Manager Documents allow us to define input parameters of type `StringList`. How can we enumerate each value in a `StringList` within the document definition?

Eg, imagine a `StringList` input parameter that defined a list of commands to run. How could we create a new `aws:runShellScript` action for each command in the list?

The pseudo-document below shows what I'm trying to achieve - creating a a new action for each value in a `StringList`.

```
schemaVersion: "2.2"
description: "Updates services configured for the current role"
parameters:
  ListOfCommands:
    type: "StringList"
    description: "A list of commands to execute"
mainSteps:

 /* For $C in ListOfCommands: */

  - action: "aws:runShellScript"
    name: "InstallConsul"
    inputs:
      runCommand:
      - "{{$C}}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to AWS support, this is not currently possible. There is no way to enumerate any values in a *StringList* within the document itself.