# Retrieve values from parameters [StringList] in AWS::SSM::Document

Tags: list, powershell, aws-cloudformation, aws-ssm

I've created an AWS SSM Document using CloudFormation:

```
SSMDocument::
Type: AWS::SSM::Document
Properties:
  DocumentType: Command
  Content:
    schemaVersion: '2.2'
    description: Run a PowerShell script
    parameters:
      Node1:
        type: String
      Node2:
        type: String
      List:
        type: StringList
    mainSteps:
    - action: aws:runPowerShellScript
      name: PreDeploy
      precondition:
        StringEquals:
        - platformType
        - Windows
      inputs:
        timeoutSeconds: '3600'
        runCommand:
        - |
          # Retrieve values from parameters
          $IpNode1 = "{{Node1}}"
          $IpNode2 = "{{Node2}}"
          $List = "{{EnvNames}}"
```

This document contains a `PowerShell` script that is executing on newly created instances.
I'm passing parameters and one of them `($List)` has type `StringList`, the issue is that I'm getting an error:

```
Parameter "List" is "STRING_LIST" type and can't be used as a substring parameter.
```

I've tried without luck:

```
$List = "{{EnvNames}}"
$List = ["{{EnvNames}}"]
$List = @("{{EnvNames}}")
```

Comment: Did you get a solution for this?

Comment: No, only using as a string and than split by coma  `$String.Split(",")`

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51857355/aws-systems-manager-enumerate-a-stringlist-parameter-in-state-manager-document) and doesn't seem to be possible

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS Systems Manager: Enumerate a StringList Parameter in State Manager Document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51857355/aws-systems-manager-enumerate-a-stringlist-parameter-in-state-manager-document)